# Change label during button execution

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a "Connect" button which calls internal logic for network connection
I have this button which starts network connection.

```
Button connectButton = new Button("Connect");
connectButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                actiontarget.setText("Successful Connection Test!");
            }
        });
```

How I can change the button label during the action execution with label "Cancel"?
And also how I can cancel the action when the button label is "Cancel"? Maybe I need to call specific action when the button label is different?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your code snippet with the logic below. Haven't tried it but I think it should work, even I would suggest using Injection.

```
private final String CONNECT = "connect";
private final String DISCONNECT = "disconnect";

Button connectButton = new Button(CONNECT);
connectButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (connectButton.getText().equals(CONNECT)) {
            do_something();
            actiontarget.setText(DISCONNECT);
        } else {
            do_something_else();
            actiontarget.setText(CONNECT);
        }
    }
});
```

Another Idea would be to use a `ToggleButton`:

In your FXML:

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="btnConnect" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1" maxWidth="1" onAction="#actionClickedConnectBtn" text="connect"/>
```

In your Code:

```
@FXML
public void actionClickedConnectBtn(ActionEvent event) {
    if (btnConnectGpsd.isSelected()) {
        do_something();
    } else {
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Boolean flag to indicate which action to execute when the button is clicked; if the flag is true, then execute your cancel action and set the flag to false, setting your button's text to "Connect". If the flag is instead false, execute your connection action and set the flag to true, setting your button's text to "Cancel".